# Creating a random string with only certain letters and a certain length

Tags: java, random

So I want to generate a random string but only want certain characters to be the string (Only ones that can be used in a file name to be hosted so something like www.example.com/HERE.EXTENTION).

So how can I make a random string that is a length that I want with only certain letters I want.

I know I can do a for look from the length, and then use the random number and cast that to a char and add it to a string. But I don't want characters that I don't want to be added and going through a loop with all that I don't want because that would take too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this quick method:

```
String genRand(int length){
   Random rand=new Random();
   String possibleLetters = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.";   
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
      sb.append(possibleLetters.charAt(rand.nextInt(possibleLetters.length())));
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Edit `possibleLetters` to include the characters you want. Note that `\` and newlines must be escaped.

Comment: +1 for the code sample, but `AB` should be replaced by `possibleLetters`.

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry, I dug this up from old code and when renaming variables for readability I missed that...\

Comment: @user2526311: assuming rnd is an instance of Random, yes, it's correct. Why wouldn't it? Have you tested the code?

Comment: @JBNizet I did test the code and got the error "rnd cannot be resolved".

Comment: @JBNizet and OP: Sorry, I'm really mentally out of it today.

Comment: @hexafraction Do you mean 'Random' instead of rand? Because rand still can't be resolved either.

Comment: @user2526311: so you blindly copy and paste code without even understanding what it does? What could rnd be initialized to, given that you asked about random strings?

Comment: @user2526311 Again sorry. It should work. I pulled it out of a larger project and failed to make it workable and self-contained due to my own ignorance today.

Answer (score 1):

Store all your accepted letters in an array, then generate a random number between 0 and the length of this array N times, to get N indices of a letter in the array. Concatenate the letters.

EDIT:

Note that if your goal is to generate unique names, random is not the solution. A random doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the two answers -

You can have it like `<yourChoiceOfName>-<currentTime>.yourext`. This way the chances of two files with the same name is lesser.

The `currenttime` could include `milliseconds`.

In this case you have a known length i.e. length of `yourChoiceOfName` + length of `currentTime` + lenght of `yourext`.